# add a custom-background-image in wordpress once more

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, background-image

I enabled the custom backgrounds for my wordpress theme like this:

```
add_theme_support('custom-background', array(
    'default-color' => 'FFF',
    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/bg.jpg'
));
```

Than I grab the class ".custom-background" of the body, because I want to change the background-size:

```
body.custom-background {
    background-attachment: fixed!important;
    background-position: center center!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
    background-size: cover!important;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The only reason why I positioned it absolute is, because I want to add an other background with the same background properties but with a width of 1000px and a centered margin (0 auto) to blur this section with css-filters:

```
body.custom-background:before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(""); //here he should takes the custom background-image (of body.custom-background)
    background-attachment: fixed!important;
    background-position: center center!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
    background-size: cover!important;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

But of course wp do not know which is the background-image... So, how can I fix this problem - that he takes the custom background-image to the :before selector once again?

Hoping you understood what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can write following code in header.php

```
<?php $background = set_url_scheme( get_background_image() ); ?>  
<style>  
  body.custom-background:before {  
  content: "";  
  background-image: url("<?php print $background; ?>");  
  background-attachment: fixed!important;  
  background-position: center center!important;  
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;  
  background-size: cover!important;  
  height: 100%;  
  right: 0;  
  left: 0;  
  margin: 0 auto;  
  width: 1000px;  
  position: fixed;  
  z-index: -1;  
  filter: blur(10px);  
 }  
</style>
```

This will work...